# Use Facebook SDK .Net in Portable class library

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm starting to develop an App for Windows phone 8 and Windows 8 and I'm creating a portable class library to share some classes in both projects. In this PCL I would like to do some Facebook operations but when I try to add the package from Nuget I get the following error:

> Could not install package 'Facebook 6.4.2'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+wp80+win',
>   but the package does not contain any assembly references or content
>   files that are compatible with that framework. For more information,
>   contact the package author.

Is it posible to use the Facebook SDK for .NET in a shared Project for Windows phone 8 and Windows 8?

Regards.